# PHP Slim Framework Routing does only work locally

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, slim, lamp

I have built something small using the Slim Framework for routing. Everything worked perfectly locally. I have rented a Droplet now and use a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 18.04. My App is located in the location `/var/www/src/public`.

I have already added this into the `apache.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/src/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `000-default.conf` already has the correct route setted.

My `.htaccess.txt` is located in `/public` with my `index.php` which contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have already enabled `mod_rewrite` for Apache.

When I call the servers IP address the main page is loaded successfully with Slim where the routing is set like this:

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, "/index.php");
});
```

So Slim seems to be rendering my `index.php` which is in the directory `/var/www/views` correctly. This path is defined in the container like this:

```
$container['renderer'] = new PhpRenderer("../../views");
```

The problem starts when I try to reach for example the site `ip_address/player` even though it is correctly routed and was functioning locally. Trying to reach it gives me this in the browser:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /player was not found on this server.
```

I have googled for several hours trying different solutions but I just can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fixed this because I had one simple problem... the .htaccess was a .htaccess.txt. This is really embarrassing lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should not it be .htaccess instead of .htaccess.txt. What kind of OS you're at?

Comment: Would you be so kind to accept my answer it it helped you.

Comment: That was the issue I had. It was on Ubuntu 18.04